# Nvidia RAID 1 Problem. Degraded drives

Tags: raid

I had a RAID 1 on my system which has a Gigabyte GA 8N SLİ motherboard with a Nvidia chipset.(Nvidia Raid IDE ROM BIOS 4.84)

When the system was working probably there used to be an icon on the system try which showed my two RAID disks. Bu after my friend accidentally clicked on the "Remove drive safely" icon while trying to disconnect her USB, I noticed that the RAID system wasn't working. After a reboot there was suddenly a failure message during boot screen.

When I enter the Nvidia RAID setup utility (F10) I can see that both drives are degraded and that won't change even if I get into them and press R for Rebuild. Other options are only Delete and Exit.

When I boot to Windows (XP Pro 32 Bit) I can see both my disks with the same data on each of them but my RAID 1 is broken.

It's a relief to see that at least my RAID 1 was active but it's annoying not being able to rebuild it. Is there a way where I can rebuild my RAID 1 without having to delete the array and build it again? Cause I don't want to backup 400 Gigs of data and then recopy it to my drives...

(Disks 2 x Seagate ST3500418 AS SATA Drives)

Comment: Isn't this more a superuser problem than admin-related, since it sounds like this is a home system using motherboard fakeRAID? (PS-RAID isn't a backup...if the data is valuable, you might want to consider getting another drive and creating a backup routine)

Comment: "But after my friend accidentally clicked on the "Remove drive safely" icon while trying to disconnect her USB, I noticed that the RAID system wasn't working" - You need to find a better RAID solution!..........+1 to Bart, I don't think this is a Systems administration problem.

Answer (score 3):

From:

http://forums.nvidia.com/lofiversion/index.php?t11732.html

- Switch off the computer
- Open the computer
- Unplug the sata/ide cable from 1 of your 2 drives
- Reboot the computer
- Shutdown the computer and switch off
- Re-plug your sata/ide drive
- Press F10 on boot to go into the RAID bios utility and select R to rebuild, press F7 to confirm.
- Windows is now starting, and if you launch the Nvidia mediashield utility you will see that the rebuilding process is in progress.

PS : During this, i had to redefine the boot disk, bios config was lost, but don't know why.

Comment: Another reason motherboard RAID isn't great to use. I've read several posts about a RAID volume going south because the BIOS just "lost" the configuration, and if the motherboard goes you may lose your RAID unless you replace it with an identical motherboard rather than getting data back by transferring the drives to another system. Entirely depends on how it was implemented by the manufacturer.

Comment: I was going to wait until he recovered before slamming his choices. But since you bring it up, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

It's terrifying that you consider doing a backup **problematic**? Even in a home-user scenario this is just unacceptable.

Backup, Wipe, Reload. Done! Very simple. Very fast. Not risky.

Without a working backup, you will one particularly rainy night find both your drives broken or that some malware or your friends clicking has eaten all your data... so please correct this at once so we can all sleep better at night! ;)