# How to image a degraded RAID array

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, raid, raid-1, windows-server-2003

On boot in Windows 2003 I have a message "Raid Array Degraded". When I use F10 to go into the RAID utility I see this screen :

[image]

After passing through that screen the machine got stuck on reboot so I power-cycled it and this time it shows both 0 and 1 drives as being degraded !

How do I go forward from here ?

It does appear that the machine is not going to boot in its current state. Before I do anything wrt RAID utilties I would prefer to image the drives if that was possible; If I take one of the drives out of the machine; put them in an enclosure and image them to another machine will they be 'good' ?

The answer shown here https://superuser.com/a/121833/77463 says "Unplug the sata/ide cable from 1 of your 2 drives" - that seems a bit vague; does it really mean either of them and it doesn't matter which ?

Comment: You unplug the damaged drive. If you guess wrong the first try try the other drive.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks for your response. If you're able to make that an answer I'll mark it as 'Answered'. For the benefits of others I did what Scott suggested. When Drive 0 was connected the boot stopped during the BIOS check and complained it "could not find boot media" (or similar). When Drive 1 was connected the boot proceeded beyond that point ... and then hit another problem :-( ... but that's another issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You unplug the damaged drive. If you guess wrong the first try, try the other drive.